# Are there toy models of full poly-isomorphism from Inter-universal Teichmüller theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am learning Inter-universal Teichmüller theory and I am interested in the concept of full poly-isomorphism. According to "[INTER-UNIVERSAL TEICHMÜLLER THEORY I: CONSTRUCTION OF HODGE THEATERS](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory%20I.pdf)", a full poly-isomorphism emerges in, for example, $\Theta$-link between two $\Theta$-Hodge theaters i.e. the set of all isomorphisms between two data in based on frobenioid. Of course, I hardly understand Hodge theater, initial $\Theta$-data, frobenioid, and so on, but I would like to know what non-trivial results arise by using its concept. Are there simpler examples that are non-obvious phenomena that occur from it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If people knew this, then perhaps we wouldn't be in the situation we are all in regarding IUT.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I appreciate your comment to one of the most knowledgeable people on IUT. I somehow understand the circumstance surrounding IUT.

Comment: (I am very much not knowledgeable in IUT, just interested as an amateur!) More concretely, the definition is elementary, but it's really not clear how it can be used for anything super-meaningful, that I know of.